NavigationMixin in lwc embeded in screeflow
I know this topic has been reviewed a fiew times but I didn't find the problem in my code.
I created a screenflow that call my lwc. From my lwc, I want to navigate to an account record page, but nothing happen.
html :
                        <template>
                            <div class="slds-p-top_large search-form-button-list">
                                
                                <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={onCancel}></lightning-button>
                            </div>
                        </template> 

js
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getCompanies from '@salesforce/apex/TempClass.getCompanies';
import applyChanges from '@salesforce/apex/TempClass.applyChanges';

export default class inseeSearchForm extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

    @api recordId;

    onCancel(event) {
        console.log(this.recordId);
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
              recordId: this.recordId,
              objectApiName: 'Account',
              actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
}

You only have here parts of the code, but from what I read in the documentation it should work. The event onCancel is fired, the recordId is set.
I'm probably missing something but I cannot find what. If someone has any idea...
Thank you!
